# POST request return 405 on auth (nginx angular)

Tags: django, angular, nginx, debian

i'm using django and angular with nginx. I get 405 not allowed when i try to post to /auth/. 
my nginx conf:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        root /home/dev/projet-name/frontend/my-app/dist/tryangular; 


        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
 }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
 }
          location ~ ^/(api|admin)/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass SERV_IP:3031;    

 }

}
```

Djnago is on the same server. 
I don't even know where i messed up

Comment: HTTP 405 is a "Method not allowed" error. Check your Django logs, as it's unlikely this has to do with nginx.

Comment: Nothing in logs :/

Comment: You have setup django to log to file? In any case a 405 will always appear in the logs if you have setup django logging.